# node:id token from panel or view

Tags: nodes, tokens, views

I have spent 4 days looking for information on many pages without result, I would like to make a view from which to send an email with the information of a node, with view send and user view I can send emails to those I have select.

But my problem is when to send information from the title of the node, the node apparently not sent. From the panel where the view I can show the node to which I Referencing the URL node *`/% node / my_view`*, but apparently not saved when sending mail.

I've found a way to call a certain node with *`[aet: node: title]`* and *`[current-page: url: args: value: 1]`*, but does not work *`[aet: node:% [current-page: url: args: value: 1]: title]`*.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to send the fields I need from the node through to post in the view send php code, creating a variable to calculate the node id and then use that variable in the token

```
<?php 
$var=token_replace('[current-page:url:args:value:1]', array('node' => $node)); 
?>

[aet:node:<?php echo $var; ?>:title]
```

This is the list of modules:

1. **tokens,**
2. **token filter,**
3. **views send,**
4. **token tweks,**
5. **Advanced Entity Tokens,**
6. **mime mail,**
7. **mailsystem,**
8. **phpfilter**